# Сумма двумерного массива через рекурсию

Tags: javascript, массивы, рекурсия

Здравствуйте, сегодня столкнулся с такой вот задачей:

Дан двумерный массив с числами. Найдите сумму элементов этого массива используя рекурсию и не используя цикл.

Смог решить только данным способом игнорируя условия задачи (не закомиченное решение простой перебор с сложением, если через рекурсию то первая функция превращает двумерный массив в одномерный и из него уже считается сумма через рекурсию):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, [3, 4]],
  result = 0, //при рекурсии меняется на array
  sumArr = 0;

function newArr(arr) {
  for (var i = arr.length; i--;) {
    if (typeof(arr[i]) == 'number') {
      //result.push(arr[i]);
      result += +arr[i];
    }
    for (var j = arr.length; j--;) {
      if (typeof(arr[i][j]) == 'number') {
        //result.push(arr[i][j]);
        result += +arr[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
}

newArr(arr);
console.log(result);

/*function sum (result){

if(result.length > 0){
    sumArr += result[0];
    result.shift();
    sum(result);
}
}
sum(result);
console.log(sumArr);*/
```

Есть способ решить данную задачу не нарушая условий полностью через рекурсию без использования циклов?

Comment: Цикл будет более производительнее. И не будет переполнения стека, если будут огромные данные. А вот при рекурсии, возможны переполнения. По этому аккуратнее. А вобоще в вашем случае, я юзал бы, какой-нибудь `reduce`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделал без использования циклов вообще.

```js
var test = [1, 1, 1, [1, 1, [1, [1, [ [1], [1] ]], 1], 1], 1];

function arrSum(array, i = 0) {
  if (isFinite(array))
    return Number(array);
  else if (typeof array == "object" && i < array.length) // верно только если array - массив (имеет свойство length)
    return arrSum(array[i]) + arrSum(array, i + 1);
  return 0;
}

console.log(arrSum(test));
```

Answer (score 2):

2 минуты гуглинга не зная js

```
function arrSum(arr) {
  var sum = 0;
  // iterate array using forEach, better to use for loop since it have higher performance
  arr.forEach(function(v) {
    // checking array element is an array
    if (typeof v == 'object')
      // if array then getting sum it's element (recursion)
      sum += arrSum(v);
    else
      // else adding the value with sum
      sum += v
  })
  // returning the result
  return sum;
}
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665228/sum-all-integers-in-a-multidimensional-array-javascript)

Comment: Я поражаюсь, первая галка по метке js :)

Comment: Поздравляю)))))

Comment: По факту `.forEach()` - это тот же самый цикл.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [[3,2], [6, 5], [5, 4]];
var sum =  0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        sum += arr[i][j];
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

на всякий случай вдруг кому пригодится

Comment: В вопросе ведь четко прописано условие "не используя цикл".